# Create a rotation matrix from a position and a look at position

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation

I am trying to create a function that returns a rotation matrix from a vertex describing a position and another vertex describing a point that the object at the first position is looking at. I have the below code so far:

```
const Matrix4 Matrix4::createRotation(const Vertex& pos, const Vertex& lookat)
{
    Vector3 vz = lookat - pos;
    vz.normalize();
    Vector3 vx = Vector3::cross(Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), vz);
    vx.normalize();
    Vector3 vy = Vector3::cross(vz, vx);

    Matrix4 rotation (  vx.x,   vy.x,   vz.x,   0,
                        vx.y,   vy.y,   vz.y,   0,
                        vx.z,   vy.z,   vz.z,   0,
                        0,      0,      0,      1);
    return rotation;
}
```

That is producing the wrong results at the moment and I am pretty sure it lays within the constructor of the rotation Matrix4 variable.

This function is going to be used in conjunction with an inverse translation matrix to build a camera's view matrix.

Would anyone be able to explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Two vectors is insufficient information to generate a *unique* rotation matrix.

Comment: That code looks fine.  What is the problem?

Comment: You want a matrix that will rotate `pos` to make it parallel to `lookat-pos`, is that right?

Comment: You're code looks fine. Depending on where you use that transformation matrix, you might have to transpose it.

Comment: Beta - I want the matrix to be used to create the camera view matrix (by multiplying it with the inverse translation matrix).

Mikael - I am transposing it withing the function that calls this function. But if you say this is correct then I am clearly going wrong somewhere else! Hmmm, I will have a think and make sure I reply with the answer when I figure this out.